# Server-side logging of html generated by dynamic site

Tags: apache

I'm curious about how to capture the dynamic html generated via php, aspx..., server-side, just as page requests themselves are logged.

Is this a scripting task (using python for instance), a web-server log format configuration setting (I've searched Apache's docs but could only find the usual log formatting directives) or a totally different approach?

Comment: Are you attempting to log the final HTML output for each and every page request? It might be more efficient to just directly call the logging methods within the code for specific data you want logged. Otherwise, you can take a look at [Output Buffers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) for PHP

Comment: Yes, I'd heard that web server settings or plugins would log HTML output for each page request. I'll look into calling logging methods within the script, probably filtering much that isn't required. Thanks.